# Possible uses for Intersect

Tags: c#, linq

I have two queries that produce the same output. One is using the Intersect extension method, the other is a cross join.

There are other ways of also doing the same thing such as a cross join or a normal join, so what else can Intersect be used for?

```
int[] intsA = new[] {1,4,7,0,3};
int[] intsB = new[] {2,3,8,9,1};

intsA.Intersect(intsB)

(from a in intsA
 from b in intsB
 where a == b
 select a)
```

### Output

IEnumerable (2 items)
1, 3

IEnumerable (2 items)
1, 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, using intersect makes your intentions much clearer, and thus makes your code more readable. `intsA.Intersect(intsB)` immediately tells me that you're producing the set intersection; the LINQ expression requires me to parse the complete, complicated expression, just to figure out the same thing.